# Does SharpDX.Direct2D1.GeometrySink need to be Disposed explicitly?

Tags: c#, directx, direct2d, sharpdx

I'm using Direct2D through SharpDX to do some simple line drawings. I create a PathGeometry, then call Open() to get a GeometrySink and add lines to the sink. GeometrySinks are Disposable, so this is how I thought I should do it:

```
var linePath = new D2D.PathGeometry(D2dFactory);
using (var sink = linePath.Open())
{
    sink.BeginFigure(point0, D2D.FigureBegin.Hollow);
    sink.AddLine(point1);
    sink.AddLine(point2);
    sink.EndFigure(D2D.FigureEnd.Open);
    sink.Close();
}
```

This code works, but VS 2012's Code Analysis says that I should not Dispose the GeometrySink two times. Is that really happening here? Maybe when I call `sink.Close()`? If that's the case, I should get rid of the `using()` statement. What's the right way to use GeometrySink ?

Answer (score 2):

I've profiled a SharpDx application with Ants profiler, the GeometrySink objects are dangling in memory, after calling Dispose() explicitly on the GeometrySink before disposing the geometry itself I've profiled again and no more GeometrySink objects were in memory. So the simple answer is YES.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your sink.Close is calling the Dispose method as well as using() is triggering it.

Comment: That's my guess too, but I'm wondering if this is a Direct2D thing, or just a SharpDX thing. Do you know how the underlying Direct2D API works? If I were writing this in C++, would I have to release the GeometrySink?

Comment: I don't sorry. I am not the graphical kind. :)